Converting Monthly economic Data into daily data for Econometric analysis
I am trying to build an econometric model (VAR, VECM or regression) to predict daily interest rates based on daily financial data as well as monthly economic data.
I am unsure how to transition the monthly data to daily data, or of the best method for doing so. I could use some sort of interpolation: however, I worry that all of these economic data variables will then become insignificant in the econometric model.
Could you suggest the best way to do this?

The only strongly defensible way to get a daily time series is IMHO to use a very highly correlated daily time series to predict it. Otherwise  thirty or so (weekends? holidays?) daily values aren't lurking inside a single monthly value to be discovered, So, perhaps the best you can  do is repeat each monthly value for each day of interest. Other procedures may create as many problems as they solve. Otherwise Google "Denton interpolation method" for a more optimistic take.

@NickCox Wouldn't using the monthly value multiple times lead to vastly underestimating noise?  This problem seems intractable to me, but I am not a time series person.

There are various ways to use data that is sampled at different frequencies. One is MIDAS (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed-data_sampling). You could also google "mixed frequency VARs." Most papers I have seen use monthly and quarterly data, but I don't see why you wouldn't be able to use daily and monthly data.

@PeterFlom Absolutely. But economists appear to do things like this quite frequently.

Hi Joshua: If you build a time-series model for the monthly data, say an ARIMA model, then there is a methodology to figure out what the equivalent daily model is. It's pretty complicated but this kind of question came up a few months ago and I investigated it and found the relevant research and papers and eventually understood them. If you want them, let me know. It's a fairly large endeavor to step into, ( the papers aren't trivial ) but probably, besides MIDAS, the only other way to go.

@mlofton: An answer giving an overview - even a brief one - of this research, & referencing the papers you mention would doubtless be useful to anyone coming across this question.

Scortchi: That's a great suggestion. When I get home tonight, I'll make an answer ( even though it's not really an answer ) with the references that led me to eventually understand what was going on.  It's quite an interesting topic and I got lucky to find the paper that made it eventually click but I really needed all three.

I found this documentation: "Temporal Disaggregation of Time Series" https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/sax-steiner.pdf seems to be of interest

Thanks Ggjj11: That approach seems to be different from the one I spoke about but could be just as useful or more. I can't comment on it because I'm not familar with it.

Background: Around 2 months ago, the thread here started and went on for a while.
Time scaling of AR(1) process for modelling financial returns
I got a lot out of it and one of the things I looked into was the methodology for taking say a daily ARIMA model with known parameters and converting to say an ARIMA model that's a model for say the monthly sum of that daily data. What is the relationship between the original parameters and the new parameters.
Clearly, the forecasts should be related in the sense that the 30 day forecast for the daily model should bear some relationship to the monthly forecast of the monthly model.
I only went through the ARIMA derivation of Silverstrini but his paper contains later derivations for the more general case so it's possible that the VAR could be covered in his paper also. The paper generalizes more and more as it goes on. It uses ideas from the other two papers
which is why they are all in some way linked together.
Anyway, that's the gist of what the papers contain. How to go back and forth between two models whose frequencies are different and the lower frequency data is a sum of the data in the higher frequency ( the daily data summed is the monthly data). Silvestrini explains it better than I can right at the beginning of the paper before he gets into the gory details.
The funny thing is that each of the 3 papers that I link to below complements the other two quite nicely. Originally, I was just working with (Box and Tiao) and Brewer and almost gave up. Then, somehow, fortune arrived and I found Silvestrini's older paper. Without that, I don't think it would have worked out.  Later on I found a more updated version of the Silverstrini paper which is the one I'm linking to below.
Overall, I would have to say that, the first one, which is Silvestrini's, is probably the clearest and provides the most coverage and clarity. So if you want to just go through that one, that might be enough. The other two were written well before the Silvestrini paper.
#==================================================================
11-01-2024: HERE ARE THE LINKS.
THIS IS FREELY AVAILABLE
https://www.academia.edu/22540805/Temporal_Aggregation_of_Univariate_and_Multivariate_Time_Series_Models_A_Survey
THIS ONE MAY BE DIFFICULT TO GET FOR FREE
https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0304407673900158
THIS ONE ALSO MAY BE DIFFICULT TO GET FOR FREE.
https://www.jstor.org/stable/2284454
